# Session Maintenance for Login Page

Tags: cocoa, session, authentication, nsurlconnection

My Requirement: I want to send login details(email, password) to server, have to maintain session for valid username.

How to create & maintain a session using "NSURLConnection" of iphone SDK?

If you found any Tutorials/Code snippets on this issue,Please post the corresponding linke here.

Advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/login.php?email=username@yahoo.com&pwd=pass"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection release];
[request release];
```

Comment: Hi john, Thanks for reply. My query is:-  if any user enter his account information, a session will be created at server-side & , session will be expired when a user signout from his account. so, how to maintain this session identifier in my iphone app , to get user details, how to kill the session when user logout , in iphone application... waiting for your reply..Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi ramyauk,
Even I am looking for the same a sample code perhaps.
But in ur scenario , u have to understand that the session is maintained by the server and not any client (includes iphone and browsers) hence u have to use the same connection to do the request, whether ur timeout (session expired) will be communicated to u by the server. In my case, I wann to try to maintain a same connection with the server and pool and refresh it.

Comment: Ameya, I got your point. I want to use cookies concept in my app. i checked many examples related to cookie creation(nshttpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage).But, i wasn't clear with that.Can you tell me, where& which method of NSURLConnection can be used to create a cookie, and adding new cookies to cookies Array.can you post a sample of code? Thank You.

Comment: I got the solution in creating new cookie, adding it to the cookie storage.